# Dynamic Temporal Control with both: aggregate date and time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, temporal

I have a data frame with both, dates such as 2021-01-01 and times such as 11:38:17. The frame consists of 1.000 cells.
I would like to use the dynamic temporal control function to show data at a given point of date and time of day.
Unfortunately I can only animate the day. As soon as I want to change the step towards hours, I face to problem to tell QGIS where it can find the time of the data set.

Which query can I use to aggregate date and time to one column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `concat` in the field calculator as follows:

```
concat("date", "time")
```

`"date"` — field with years and months; `"time"` — field with time.

In the description of the function you will see examples.

Maybe combining the columns will not be enough. To do this, you need:

1. Resave the layer in GeoPackage or GeoJSON (SHP does not recognize the date and time together).
2. Create a new field with a date and time value as follows (in the field calculator too):
   — select the type of the new column "Date and time";
   — in the field with the expression, write the name of the combined field. For example, `"datetime"`.

If I understood the question correctly, then the method is.